# assert post worked Django

Tags: django, testing, post, assertion

I just wrote some tests case about my forms, here is one :

```
def test_department_admin_creation(self):

    nb = Department.objects.count()
    response = self.client.post(self.url, {"name" : 'department', "organization" : self.organization})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(nb+1,Department.objects.count())
```

And I'm wondering why the last assertion doesn't work while the status_code assertion did.

```
 AssertionError: 2 != 1
```

Thank you !

Comment: I don't know what "the status_code's one" is, but that test is clearly telling you that the submission did not succced and the department was not created; you presumably have a 200 because the invalid form was re-displayed. Normally a successful POST would redirect to a new page, which is a 302.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, I fixed it changing "self.organization" to "self.organization.id" and I obviously also changed the expected status code... Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Roseman, I figured out the solution :

I was passing an "organization" in my post params, while the form needed an integer (the organization's id).
The right code was :

```
    nb = Department.objects.count()
    response = self.client.post(self.url, {"name" : 'department', "organization" : self.organization.id})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
    self.assertEqual(nb+1,Department.objects.count())
```